# Ultrachart infragistics

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

I have an asp .net application which uses an infragistics Ultrachart as a Radar chart. Now the chart is like below

[image]

Is it possible to add text next to the radians and levels like below? Any examples please?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. I made small samples (WinForm and ASP applications) specially for you. You could find it in Infragistics community : http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/78069/394223.aspx

Let me know if you have any questions.!

Comment: Maybe you should post some relevant code here also, to be just in one place in your answer. This link may be broken for a few months and your answer will be useless.